# i am getting error in phpunit's vendor file when i use compose update

Tags: php, phpunit

**# error messages

## **

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/xampp/htdocs/random_experiments/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/_files/source_for_branched_exec_lines.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "PHP2014",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Syntax error: unexpected token '&'",
    "source": "PHP",
    "startLineNumber": 61,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 61,
    "endColumn": 10
}]
```

error in code

```
 __construct
    (
        & (error is here)
        $var
        =
        1
    )
```

i have tried to ask chatGPT but i found no answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP and PhpUnit do you have ?

Ampresands before a parameter (passing by refference) were deprecated in php 5.3 and completely removed in PHP7.